How do I test a Spring Boot application that uses JAX-RS/Jersey?
This question is based on the Testing the Web Layer guide for Spring Boot:

We'll start with a @SpringBootTest that passes when we use a controller; this is very similar to the example in the guide.
We'll refactor the Spring Boot application to use a JAX-RS/Jersey endpoint instead of a controller; the test now fails.

The question is how we fix the test.
Testing an Application with a Controller
This is very similar to the example in the guide. Here's the code for the controller and the application:
package org.example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public final class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public @ResponseBody String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }
}

package org.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class GreetingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GreetingApplication.class, args);
    }
}

Here is the corresponding test class for the application:
package org.example;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public final class GreetingApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void helloWorld() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().string("Hello, world!"));
    }
}

Here is how the code behaves:

If you run the application (e.g. ./gradlew bootRun) and manually test it, it works.
If you run the tests (e.g., ./gradlew build), the tests pass.

Testing an Application with a JAX-RS/Jersey Endpoint
We'll make the following changes to the code:

delete GreetingController
add GreetingEndpoint
add JerseyConfig

Here is the code for the classes we'll add:
package org.example;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Path("/")
public final class GreetingEndpoint {

    @GET
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }
}

package org.example;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public final class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(GreetingEndpoint.class);
    }
}

Here is how the code behaves:

If you run the application (e.g. ./gradlew bootRun) and manually test it, it works.
If you run the tests (e.g., ./gradlew build), the tests fail.

How do we fix GreetingEndpointTest so that the tests pass?

If you want to repro this yourself, here are the contents of build.gradle.kts:
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.4.0"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:4.0.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey:3.4.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.4.0")

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.11.3")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.4.0")

    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.11.3")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.11.3")
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

tasks.named<Test>("test") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


Answer:

TestRestTemplate can be used with JAX-RS/Jersey.
MockMvc cannot be used with JAX-RS/Jersey.


MockMvc is closely coupled with Spring's MVC architecture; it will only work with a Spring controller.
There's an example of using TestRestTemplate in the Testing the Web Layer guide. For the code in this question, the following test will pass:
package org.example;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public final class GreetingApplicationTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    void helloWorld() {
        assertThat(restTemplate.getForObject(String.format("http://localhost:%d", port), String.class))
                .isEqualTo("Hello, world!");
    }
}


package org.example;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;  // Import assertion library for fluent style assertions

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;  // Import JUnit 5 Test annotation
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;  // Import for auto-wiring beans
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;  // Import Spring Boot Test annotation
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;  // Import WebEnvironment
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;  // Import TestRestTemplate for testing REST APIs
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.server.LocalServerPort;  // Import LocalServerPort to get the random port used in tests

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)  // Set up the Spring Boot test with a random port for each run
public final class GreetingApplicationTest {

    @LocalServerPort  // Inject the random port assigned to the test server
    private int port;

    @Autowired  // Auto-wire the TestRestTemplate bean to send HTTP requests
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test  // Mark this method as a test method to be executed by JUnit
    void helloWorld() {
        // Create the URL using the injected random port
        String url = String.format("http://localhost:%d", port);

        // Use the TestRestTemplate to send a GET request to the generated URL
        // Assert that the response body matches the expected string "Hello, world!"
        assertThat(restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class))
                .isEqualTo("Hello, world!");  // Verify the result using an assertion
    }
}

